# Add a where clause to IQueryable without using generics

Tags: c#, lambda, expression, linq-to-entities, ef-core-6.0

I'm trying to write a piece of code that is going to be used to select a value from a database.   As a test I have already created this test version of the method that "works" but isn't great.

```
private object? FindObjectByProperty(IQueryable query, PropertyInfo primaryKeyProperty, object lookupValue)
{
    object? result = null;
    foreach (var value in query)
    {
        if (!primaryKeyProperty.GetValue(value)!.Equals(lookupValue))
            continue;

        result = value;
        break;
    }

    return result;
}
```

The code will iterate through the query and find the first entry that matches the Equals.   However, if the query contains millions of rows, as it's likely to when the IQueryable is really a DbSet (Which in this use case it is. Only I don't know what T, as it could be any of the DbSets on my EF Core data context.

What I'd like to end up with is something that looks something along these lines....

```
private object? FindObjectByProperty(IQueryable query, PropertyInfo primaryKeyProperty, object lookupValue)
{
    return query.Where( x => x.*primaryKeyProperty* == lookupValue).FirstOrDefault();
}
```

The above code is pseudo code, the problems that I have is that query does not have a .Where available.  Also *primaryKeyProperty* will need to be translated to the actual property.

The idea is that when this code is executed, ultimately executing the query, will generate a  sql statement which selects a single item and returns it.

Can anyone help with solving this?

Update:
I'm working on a solution to this, so far this is what I've come up with

```
//using System.Linq.Dynamic.Core;

private object? FindObjectByProperty(IQueryable query, PropertyInfo primaryKeyProperty, object lookupValue)
{
    var parameter = Expression.Parameter(query.ElementType);
    var e1 = Expression.Equal(Expression.Property(parameter, primaryKeyProperty.Name), Expression.Constant(lookupValue));
    var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<object, bool>>(e1, parameter);
    return query.Where(lambda).FirstOrDefault();
}
```

This is failing on the because the func uses Object, when it really needs the real type.  Trying to figure that bit out.  This is getting closer.

Update #2:
Here's the answer that I needed

```
private object? FindObjectByProperty(IQueryable query, PropertyInfo primaryKeyProperty, object lookupValue)
{
    var parameter = Expression.Parameter(query.ElementType);
    var propExpr = Expression.Property(parameter, primaryKeyProperty);
    var lambdaBody = Expression.Equal(propExpr, Expression.Constant(lookupValue, primaryKeyProperty.PropertyType));
    var filterEFn = Expression.Lambda(lambdaBody, parameter);
    return query.Where(filterEFn).FirstOrDefault();
}
```

The difference is that the Expression.Lambda no longer tries to define the func using generics.  This is the only change that I needed to do to make the code function as I wanted.

In the test case that I was using, the T-SQL produced to lookup the value looks like this...

```
SELECT TOP(1) [g].[Id], [g].[Deleted], [g].[Guid], [g].[Name], [g].[ParentId]
FROM [Glossaries].[Glossaries] AS [g]
WHERE [g].[Id] = CAST(3 AS bigint)
```

The table [Glossaries].[Glossaries] is provided by the input query.  The column name Id is provided by the primaryKeyProperty, and the number 3 is provided by the lookupValue.

This is perfect for my needs as I simply needed to select that one row and nothing else, so that I can effectively lazy load the my object property when I need it, and not before.

Also this code will be reused for many different tables.

Comment: What is the *actual* problem you think can be solved by this? There's no point at all in using an ORM without strongly typed classes. The very name is Object to Relational Mapper. LINQ is a query language for an ORM, not a replacement for SQL. If you don't know what type you want to map to, what *will* you map to?

Comment: `However, if the query contains millions of rows` then don't use an ORM. ORMs aren't ETL tools or SQL generators. Their job is to let you work with relational data as if you were working with in-memory objects. They do that by loading and persisting *graphs* of related objects. That abstraction breaks down if you start working with streams or sets

Comment: `as it's likely to when the IQueryable is really a DbSet` that doesn't make much sense. A DbSet is neither a table nor a container nor a query. It's essentially a single-entity repository, containing the metadata for its type. You use it to query and load instances of that type, or save changes to instances of the type. You can use LINQ to query that repository

Comment: Is `query` really an `IQueryable<T>`? Is a `PropertyInfo` really how the caller gets the key property?

Comment: To answer the questions.   query is an IQueryable  not IQueryable<T>.    If I was able to use iQueryable<T> the problem would be a whole lot easier.

Comment: The actual problem that I'm working on is that I'm creating a tool that will generate a live audit trail for my database.   Whenever the ORM changes data I want it audited.   I want this process to be automated, so that we don't have to keep going over old ground making boiler plate code to make the audit work for inserts updates and deletes.   There is a requirement that will mean that EFCore may not have loaded up an object that I need to be able to create the relevant audit record, so what I need to do is load that item up.

Comment: The Query is one of the DBSet<T> from the database context, but it could be any of the datasets, i.e. any of the tables.  What I'm trying to do is get the object from the DBSet<T> for a given primary key look up value. Following a foreign key relationship.   However, until the code is running, I do not know which dataset I'm trying to access, as it could be any of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to build add `Where` to an `IQueryable` where you don't have access to the actual `IQueryable<T>`, you need to take a step back (or up?) from calling `Where` at compile-time, and build the `Where` call at runtime, as well as the predicate lambda:

```
public static class DBExt {
    public static IQueryable WherePropertyIs<T2>(this IQueryable src, PropertyInfo propInfo, T2 propValue) {
        // return src.Where(s => s.{propInfo} == propValue)
        // (T s)
        var sParam = Expression.Parameter(src.ElementType, "s");
        // s.propInfo
        var propExpr = Expression.Property(sParam, propInfo);
        // s.{propInfo} == propValue
        var lambdaBody = Expression.Equal(propExpr, Expression.Constant(propValue));
        // (T s) => s.{PropInfo} == propValue
        var filterEFn = Expression.Lambda(lambdaBody, sParam);

        var origQuery = src.Expression;
        // IQueryable<Tx>.Where<Tx, Expression<Func<Tx, bool>>>()
        var whereGenericMI = typeof(Queryable).GetMethods("Where", 2).Where(mi => mi.GetParameters()[1].ParameterType.GenericTypeArguments[0].GenericTypeArguments.Length == 2).First();
        // IQueryable<T>.Where<T, Expression<Func<T, bool>>>()
        var whereMI = whereGenericMI.MakeGenericMethod(src.ElementType);
        // src.Where(s => s.{propertyInfo} == propValue)
        var newQuery = Expression.Call(whereMI, origQuery, filterEFn);

        return src.Provider.CreateQuery(newQuery);
    }
}
```

Comment: My update, came from code very similar to this,  however it doesn't work.  I am not using IQueryable<T> and do not know what T is at compile time,  it could be any an ojbect from any of the datasets from my datacontext.

Comment: @ColinDawson In that case, it is a little more complicated, see my answer update.

Comment: This isn't a perfect answer to the problem, however, it has given me all the information that I needed to be able to get it working!   I've posted a follow up update with the working version of the code just in case anyone needs to solve the same problem in the future.

Comment: @ColinDawson I am not sure how `query.Where` is working in your query, but as long as it works...

Comment: add the nuget package System.Linq.Dynamic.Core, that gives the .Where